# QCategoryAxis minor tick marks not visible

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcharts

In PyQt5, I'm trying to enable the minor tick marks of a QcategoryAxis.
Using setMinorGridLineVisible and setMinorTickCount methods does not seem to work, as it does with a simple QValueAxis. Is this a bug, or am I missing something? With the code snippet below, the category labels and the major ticks appear just fine, but the minor tick marks are missing.

```
Xaxis = QCategoryAxis()
Xaxis.setTitleText("Time [s]")
Xaxis.setMax(180)
Xaxis.setMinorTickCount(5)
Xaxis.setMinorGridLineVisible(True)
Xaxis.append("0", 0)
Xaxis.append("50", 50)
Xaxis.append("100",100)
Xaxis.append("150", 150)
```